# Webcam Feed Black Dell Latitude 5540 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, dell, webcam

When using the integrated webcam in cheese, guvcview, or Zoom, the feed appears as a black screen with a slashed camera icon.

I attempted to fix with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta
sudo apt install oem-somerville-tentacool-meta
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo systemctl poweroff
```

as outlined [by Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000203830/webcam-is-not-detected-on-xps-13-plus-9320-laptops-running-ubuntu-22-04)

I also selected the Broadcom Corp and Intel Corporation drivers under the "Additional Drivers" in the "software and updates" application.

running

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

returns

```
Virtual Camera (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0

Integrated_Webcam_FHD: Integrat (usb-0000:00:14.0-6):
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/media0
```

As I understand it, this means Ubuntu is connected and recognizes the devices.

The webcam is enabled in the BIOS.

I am at a bit of a loss as to what to try next. Your time and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Open settings in Cheese. Try changing camera. Does it help?

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunately, I have already tried that. The virtual camera gives an image akin to SMPTE color bars and both of the Integrated web cams give the black screen with the slashed camera icon.

Comment: Does anything happen when you run `sudo cheese -d "Intel MIPI Camera"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I also tried that per Dell's recommendation. The webcam LED lights for a moment, then goes out and the feed displays the black background with the slashed camera.